# Can i convert input text to downloadable mp3 in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox to get text input from the users. How do I convert the inputted text to speech downloadable in `.mp3`format using Javascript?

Comment: Save it as a text file and rename it to `.mp3`?  How do you plan to convert *text* to *audio*?

Comment: I have done text to speech in javascript but now i want text to mp3 file which is downloadable.

Comment: In the end this question asks for a recommendation of a tool or library, that means it is considered off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Chekout [responsivevoice](https://responsivevoice.org/)
It is a HTML5-based Text-To-Speech library to provide voice features for web sites and apps across all devices.

Comment: I want to download the audio in a mp3 or whatever format.